# Count sub-strings in a cell from a range of cells (excel)

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

Suppose in cells `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` there are three strings, one for each of them.
I would count how many times the strings in `A2` and `A3` are contained in `A1`. My solution is:

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;A2;"")))/LEN(A2) + (LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;A3;"")))/LEN(A3)
```

The result is correct, but I need to write the interval A2:A3 not in an explicit way (for example I could be interested in searching in another interval, say X1:X100, and of course I can't write explicitly the sum of 100 addends). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel can deal with vectors fairly nicely:

```
=SUM((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,A2:A100,"")))/LEN(A2:A100))
```

Comment: Thanks! However, it only works in Excel, but not in google spreadsheets. Are there any reasons?

Comment: Solved. In google sheets we need to write =ArrayFormula(...). Thanks again.